# Using angular2. Dynamic event handling in real time

Tags: events, angular, dynamic

Using angular2. How to do mouse dragging on a `input type="range"` and then dynamically update an calculation with value `[(ngModel)]="value"` An event (it works with `(mouseUp_` but not with dragging)

would be something like this in the html `<input type="range" [(ngModel)]="value"..`
and then in the typescript file update the calculation with the value in `"value"`.
A similar thing would be `(click)="action()"` But I want it to happen in real time when the user is dragging the `input="range"`

Comment: automatic update while user dragging the slider. Calling a function at movement at using the new value from the slider.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`oninput` event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_oninput.asp).

Checkout this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/EAZwk76i6M6rBrmD1u1r?p=preview

Comment: Thanks you very much! I have been trying out a lot, but this was just great gave me cleaner code.